# Implode array -> check characters -> inset to Database

Tags: mysql, arrays, preg-replace, implode

I got a Array like this....

```
Array ( [register] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [firstname] => Marc [surname] => hamster [company] => 12345678 [position] => !\"§$%&/(hamste$r ) [1] => Array ( [country] => [zip] => [city] => [street] => ) [2] => Array ( [homepage] => [phone] => [mobile] => ) [3] => Array ( [email] => [password1] => [password2] => ) ) )
```

I put these in a Database like this:

```
// build query...
$sql  = "INSERT INTO table";

// implode keys of $array...
$sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";

// implode values of $array...
$sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

// execute query...
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

But before i want to replace special Characters like this....to avoid SQL inject

```
$text= preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-öäüÖÄÜ@ ]/","",$text);
```

Is there a simple and smart way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to loop through the array first* - for example:

```
foreach ( $columns as $value){
     $value  = preg_replace etc...;
}
```

Then run the query.

*before you build the query I guess.